# FlexBoxGrid2 issue with rows

Tags: html, css, flexboxgrid

I`m doing one project using FlexBoxGrid2 and have an issue with rows. I need to add many rows one goes next by each other, but adding the second row I see that it is situated behid the first row, not under as I need it. Delete of "position: fixed;" in CSS for "header_container" helps to solve that, but I need first row (nav bar) to be fixed. Please advise if there is any solution for that as I completely stucked here.
Thanks.

```css
.header_container {
  max-width: 1124px;
  height: 72px;
  padding: 0 55px 0 55px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 16px 0px #26262629;
}
.header_container:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.logo {
  float: left;
  width: 119.23px;
  height: 12.31px;
  padding: 20px 55px 20px 55px;
}
nav {
  float: right;
}
nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.btn {
  width: 78px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  color: #1D1D1D;
  font-family: roboto;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 1000;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
  margin-top: 16px;
}
.line {
  max-width: 80%;
  width: 956px;
  height: 1x;
  color: #757575;
  border-bottom: solid 1px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>ExamPro</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/flexboxgrid2@7.2.1/flexboxgrid2.css">
</head>
  <body>
    <header>
  <div class="header_container">
    <a href=""> <img src="" alt="logo" class="logo"/></a>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><button class="btn">Войти</button></li>
        <li><a href=""> <img src="" alt="basket" class="basket"/></a>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
    <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
        <div class="line">search</div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
   <div class="container">
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
        
    </div>
</div>
</div>
     
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I found only one way to solve issue-to add more padding to the first row after navbar and stay position:fixed in this case.

Answer (score 0):

So I found it, to solve issue above you need to change position: fixed; to position: sticky;and all works well.

Comment: It would be helpful to explain why this change works, i.e., what the different behaviors of these two values is.

Comment: This change works as with it I can do navigation bar fixed and use flexboxgrid without bugs described above.

Comment: Unfortunately when it comes to more content and you need to scroll "sticky" doesnt work as fixed-navbar doesn`t fix to the top as its necessary.